# Why is this an harmonic oscillator and how can I solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > Consider the system
> >     $$
> > \dot{x}=y,\quad \dot{y}=x^2-x^3.
> > $$

Of course, I can write this as
$$
x''+x^3-x^2=0.
$$

*It is said that this is an harmonic oscillator and therefore it has periodic solutions.*

Why is this an harmonic oscillator? I only know harmonic oscillators to have the form $x''+w_0x=0$.

How can I solve this equation?

I hope this is not too stupid, but why not
$$
x=\int_{t_0}^t y(s)\, dx+c_1,\quad y=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+c_2?
$$

That does not look periodic to me.

Comment: You know, it's for sure **anharmonic**, but not *a harmonic* oscillator :)

Comment: Your last section: Because the integral should be $ds$, not $dx$. You can multiply the second order equation with $\dot x$ and then integrate in this fashion.

Comment: Be careful about what your integrating / with respect to what variable. I guess that $x$ and $y$ are functions $x(t),y(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

For small perturbations of the equilibrium point it is a perturbation of a harmonic oscillator. Set $x=1+εu$ then
$$
εu''+(1+3εu+3ε^2u^2+ε^3u^3)-(1+2εu+ε^2u^2)=0\\
u''+u+2εu^2+ε^2u^3=0
$$
But I would not call the original system "harmonic". The potential function $V(x)=\frac14x^4-\frac13x^3$ enforces bounded and thus periodic orbits, however they are not circular with constant angular velocity.

---

The only interesting level set is the one containing $(x,y)=(0,0)$ as that is the other stationary point of the potential function. $V(x)=0$ has $x=\frac43$ as the other solution. If it is a homoclinic orbit or a normal periodic orbit depends on the finiteness of the period integral
$$
\frac T2=\int_0^{\frac43}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac13x^3-\frac14x^4}}
$$
Close to $x=0$ the integrand is $\sim x^{-3/2}$, thus the anti-derivative $\sim x^{-1/2}$ which gives an infinite value to the integral. Thus this level set (and only this) is not a periodic orbit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anharmonicity The point of my comment was that "an harmonic" looks too close to "anharmonic". And *anharmonic* is pretty appicable in this situation.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But can only be verified by the OP or a link to the task.

Comment: @LutzL I am not that into physics. I did not understand yet why the original ODE of order 2 is called anharmonic. What is the definitio of *harmonic* oscillator and *anharmonic* oscillator?

Comment: Well, this system can model oscillator because some initial conditions provide trajectories with oscillatory motion. But these motions are not sinusoidal (=*harmonic*) and because of that they are *anharmonic*.

Comment: This is some historical artifact, harmonic here is the same as in harmonic analysis, i.e., things expressible in trigonometric functions. In this case it is not more than what you wrote in your question, $\ddot x+\omega^2x=0$. Every other periodic process is then by definition anharmonic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I still do not see how i can solve the equation and, in particular, how I get periodic solutions/ trajectories.

Comment: @Evgeny: Since the energy function $E(x,v)=\frac12v^2+\frac14x^4-\frac13x^3$ only has bounded level sets, all solutions are periodic.

Comment: @LutzL Which theorem does tell me that, in case the Hamilton function is bounded, solutions are periodic?

Comment: @Rhjg: As you ask, I'm not so sure about it. I would say the angular velocity around the minimum point $(x,y)=(x,v)=(1,0)$ is always positive, but $(0,0)$ is an unstable stationary point and thus may be end point to a [homoclinic orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoclinic_orbit).

Comment: It's important that level sets of Hamiltonian are bounded (as sets on the plane), not Hamiltonian itself (as function). And it's also important that level set doesn't contain equilibria. In that case each connected component of this level set is a the whole trajectory. Because that trajectory is closed, it's periodic -- it's the common property for all autonomous ODEs (fast proof for this is the following: $\mathbf{x}(t)$ and $\mathbf{x}(t+T)$ define solutions that solve the same IVP, therefore they are the same solutions).